# Bootstrap modal Container upon click, won't popup modal

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-modal

So I am trying to get a container class to be clicked instead of a button type, but upon clicking it won't pop up the modal and instead it gets dim dark screen, does anyone knows what is going on?

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<!-- Font awesome-->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.21/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">
<script src="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


<div class="notification-item" data-toggle="modal" data-target=".bd-example-modal-lg">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-3 col-sm-3 col-3 text-center">
      <img src="../images/bell.png" class="w-50 rounded-circle">
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-8 col-sm-8 col-8">
      <strong class="text-info">David John</strong>
      <div class="breakdiv">

      </div>
      <small class="text-warning">27.11.2015, 15:00</small>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<--Modal-->
  <div class="modal fade bd-example-modal-lg" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg  modal-dialog-right" role="document">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header ">
          <h2 style="font-family: Lato; font-size:29pt; font-weight:bold;" class="modal-title " id="exampleModalLongTitle">...</h2>
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                        </button>
        </div>


        <div class="modal-body">
          <form class="form-horizontal " id="step2">
            <div class="form-row" id="comNameAndTypeContainer">
              Details
            </div>
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-J6qa4849blE2+poT4WnyKhv5vZF5SrPo0iEjwBvKU7imGFAV0wwj1yYfoRSJoZ+n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't load the bootstrap which is essential for the model. Please check the working fiddle below.

one more thing, you forgot to add `!` near `<--Modal-->`

```css
.notification-item {
  cursor:pointer;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<!-- Font awesome-->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.21/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">

<div class="notification-item" data-toggle="modal" data-target=".bd-example-modal-lg">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-3 col-sm-3 col-3 text-center">
      <img src="../images/bell.png" class="w-50 rounded-circle">
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-8 col-sm-8 col-8">
      <strong class="text-info">David John</strong>
      <div class="breakdiv">

      </div>
      <small class="text-warning">27.11.2015, 15:00</small>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<!--Modal-->
  <div class="modal fade bd-example-modal-lg" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg  modal-dialog-right" role="document">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header ">
          <h2 style="font-family: Lato; font-size:29pt; font-weight:bold;" class="modal-title " id="exampleModalLongTitle">...</h2>
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                        </button>
        </div>


        <div class="modal-body">
          <form class="form-horizontal " id="step2">
            <div class="form-row" id="comNameAndTypeContainer">
              Details
            </div>
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: It is working here. I think you have another error in your HTML that's why it is not working. You should check the console, is there any error?

Comment: I have the following scripts added in the edited version, it's the one I'm using

Comment: You didn't add the bootstrap.css in the post.

Comment: I have added your scripts (bootstrap4) in the answer along with the bootstrap CSS. please check again.

Comment: my apology, apparently, I've more scripts on top too, please check the edited version

Comment: ok, I have updated the post again with your script. Keep in mind, do not use multiple versions of any CSS or JS, as you are using two different versions of jQuery and bootstrap.js. So I kept only a single version.

Comment: not sure why is it working for you in the snippet but mine still isn't showing up. I will just tick it anyway ty

Comment: You should check the console, it might have some warning/error. And also you can try to debug by adding/removing CSS/JS